# Как добавить данные из одного input в любой блок (по выбору: 1-ый, 2-ой, 3-ий или 4-ый)?

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-events

Нужно сделать возможность добавления текста из элемента input в отдельные блоки. (Сейчас текст выводится из-за заранее выбранного класса (class="textOutput3"), нужно чтобы пользователь сам выбирал куда ему вывести данные - в 1-ый, 2-ой, 3-ий или 4-ый блок.

Из идей - создать ещё один input с type = "number" или select от 1 до 4 и объединить его с уже имеющимся input который есть, чтобы пользователь писал текст, выбирал цифру и функция на js выводила значение из входных данных (не знаю как реализовать). Либо просить пользователя ввести в input в начале предложения цифру и функция на js выводила текст в блок согласно цифре которую написал пользователь в начало предложения - 1, 2, 3 или 4 (тоже не знаю как реализовать).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnVKU.png)

Comment: Или добавить 4 кнопки - "Кнопка 1", "Кнопка 2", "Кнопка 3", "Кнопка 4". Тогда пользователь вводит текст и выбирает нужную ему кнопку и текст выводится соответственно по выбранной кнопке.

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/#12120)

Comment: Или тег select с нужным выбором, куда размещать. Или radioButton с выбором. И при клике на кнопку добавить, проверять выбранное значение и по нему добавлять значение...